# Trigger after insert not working?

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stud
AFTER INSERT ON error
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (age < 0) THEN
RAISE.APPLICATION.ERROR(-2000,'No negative');
END IF;
END;
```

This is my trigger code. Actually I am a newbie in DBMS. And I am getting an error!

```
ERROR at line 3: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:

   , * & - + / at mod remainder rem 
     as
   from into || multiset bulk year DAY_

1. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stud
2. AFTER INSERT ON error
3. FOR EACH ROW
4. BEGIN
5. IF (age < 0) THEN
```

I have wrote this according to the syntax I referenced! whats wrong I have no idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR
```

not

```
RAISE.APPLICATION.ERROR
```

and

```
if (:new.age < 0)
```

not

```
if (age < 0)
```

The `:new` and `:old` qualifiers are more relevant in an `update` trigger, because they allow you to reference the values currently in the database as well as the new values coming in through the update statement. An `insert` trigger only has access to `:new` values, because there is no row currently in the database. I confess I'm not 100% sure the `:new` qualifier is mandatory in an `insert` trigger, but even if not I'd suggest it's good practise to use it as it makes for clearer code.

Comment: Ya it worked! Can you please tell my why ":new" is needed and what is it actually?

Comment: I've updated my answer with further explanation. Don't forget you can upvote or accept it if it's solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the mistake about `.` instead of `_` in `RAISE.APPLICATION_ERROR`.

You must specify the scope of values, whether `old` or `new`. Else, how would Oracle know whether your `IF` condition is r`eferring` to old or new value?

There is a reason why Oracle has a clause about `referencing old as old and new as new`. The state of the values needs to be pretty clear, whether it is the old value or the new value. Because, mentioning only the `column name` without telling Oracle whether to check the old or new value is vague. It is the value which needs to be validated.